# Jquery как нажать кнопку в iframe jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как нажимая кнопку поверху айфрейма, нажать другую кнопку в айфрейме? Айфрейм на моем сайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[name=temp_iframe]').contents().find('button').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Но только если фрейм и страница с одного домена

Comment: если не сложно, напишите как наоборот? (из iframe в родитель)

Comment: Например как-то так: window.parent.document.getElementById('#target').click();

Comment: `getElementById('target')`